# Drupal: how rewrite all urls so that the instal directory isn't included in the link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I installed drupal on my site at say, `example.co.uk/portfolio`.

All the links are showing as `example.co.uk/portfolio/project-1`.

I want it to be `example.co.uk/project-1`

How can I use rewrite rules or whatever so that wherever there is a link that has the `/portfolio` directory showing, that it will not show it in the href at all? I want to be able to hide that the site is installed in a directory and want it to show everything from the root url `www.example.co.uk/`

So far,
I've messed around with `RewriteBase /` and also mapping the portfolio to the main root via:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /portfolio
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this mod_rewrite rule in the .htaccess file in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^portfolio/ portfolio%{REQUEST_URI}
```